# Leetcode Problem 1009 Complement of base 10 integer

Tags: c++, binary

The complement of an integer is the integer you get when you flip all the 0's to 1's and all the 1's to 0's in its binary representation.
For example, The integer 5 is "101" in binary and its complement is "010" which is the integer 2.
Given an integer n, return its complement.

My solution -

```
class Solution {
public:
    int bitwiseComplement(int n) {
        int k=1;
        if(n==0){
            return k;
        }
        long int binary=0,i=0;
        while(n){
            long int bit=n&1;
            if(bit==0){
                bit=1;
            }
            else{
                bit=0;
            }
            binary=(bit*pow(10,i))+binary;
            n=n>>1;
            i++;
        }
        long int ans=0,j=0;
        while(binary!=0){
            long int digit=binary%10;
            ans=digit*pow(2,j)+ans;
            j++;
            binary=binary/10;
        }
        
        
        return ans;
        
    }
};
```

What is my mistake here?
All my testcases ran successfully but When input is 299475, Output is 224816, Expected output is 224812.
Please help me.

Comment: But you *are* aware of `~` operator, are you???

Comment: `ans=digit*pow(2,j)+ans;` -- Do not use `pow` for integer-based problems.  The `pow` is a floating point function, and with that, all the issues that come with floating point.

Comment: you should create a [mcve], some code that you and others can compile, test, and debug. Then you should attach a debugger to see where your expectations deviate from what the code does.

Comment: Negating a bit can be done much more easily by `bit = !bit` – and I would not try to build a number such that it *looks* like binary but with base 10 – that's pretty likely going to overflow with large numbers (you'd convert 9 to 1001, one-thousand and one, what would you convert 1000, 1000000 to???).

Comment: even if `pow` was the right function, you should not use it here. Its a waste of resources to call `pow(x,i)` in a loop with loop counter `i`. Instead you should initialize a variable outside and then inside the loop `p *= x;`

Comment: I suppose the exercise is about realizing that numbers are stored in binary representations already. There is nothing to be converted.

Comment: Try that way: `int result = 0; int bit = 1; for(; n; n >>= 1, bit <<= 1) { if((n & 1) == 0) { result |= bit; } }` – much more efficient and no problematic base change within... Well: *understand* what this does and then re-implement on your own, if you want to learn something. Ask, if something is unclear.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks Got it. I am beginner, started coding 2-3 days ago, so i did not know about ~ operator.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks, Got it, BTW what does your name mean?

Comment: Well, the ~ operator was a bit too fast, though – didn't notice that you are apparently intended to drop leading ones arising from the full 32-bit complement (5 would this way get converted to -6!). One *can* use it, but then you need to mask out the surplus most significant bits...

Comment: Well, started playing around myself now – coming up with [three variants](https://godbolt.org/z/dEvhca6Mc) you might like... I personally would go on with third, should be the one getting along with least operations, on average at least (corresponds to accepted answer, but slightly more efficient)... I don't mind you copying, but strongly recommend to *understand* first what's going on. Ask, if need be ;)

Comment: Oh, and about what actually went wrong: 299475 is 100 1001 0001 1101 0011 in binary – and a number with this representation as *decimal* digits is far beyond a 32-bit LONG_MAX – sure you get overflow that way (unless you were on a 64-bit linux where long has 64 bits...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others in the comments have suggested, there's the bit-flip operator `~` that inverses all the bits in an integer

A number like "5" is this in binary. Assuming a 32-bit integer.

```
0000000 0000000 0000000 0000101
```

And so applying this:

```
int n = 5;
n = ~5;
```

Produces this for `n`:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010
```

oops, that's like -6, not 2 like the problem wanted. You need to re-twiddle those leading `1` bits and stop when you encounter the first 0 (from left to right).

Putting it altogether.

```
int bitwiseComplement(int n) {

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1; // special case
    }

    int i = ~n;
    size_t bits = sizeof(n) * 8;

    // it's always a good idea to do bit-twiddling exercises
    // in the unsigned space - especially for the right shift
    unsigned int mask = 1 << (bits-1);  // this should be 0x80000000
    while (mask & i)                    // while the bit in u matching the bit in mask are both set
    {
        i = mask ^ i;                   // toggle the bit in u to zero
        mask = mask >> 1;               // mask gets shifted (e.g. 0x80000000 to 0x40000000)
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Hm... LC did not specify how to handle the special case – if we'd return -1 now then we'd retain the `complement < original` characteristic even for the special case ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua - Leetcode has a submit test case for validating that an input of "0" returns "1".

Comment: I see... That's still lacking in the problem definition, and I have no account to test myself (and won't have...) – hint to the quality of the site???

Comment: By the way, from a mathematical point of view, what could we meaningfully do with such complement? If we added original and complement we'd get next power of two greater than original subtracted by one. In this respect 0 would be its own complement...

Comment: @Aconcagua - 99% of the Leetcode problems (and on similar sites) do not map to anything real world software engineers do (except for coding interviews) or even real world computer science problems for that matter. Most leetcode problems are user submitted. And many of them have ambigous edge cases that aren't discovered until you go to test or submit. We don't solve Leetcode problems to make us better engineers. We use it to keep our interview skills up to date. :)

Answer (score 2):

c++20 added many useful bit-related functions. If you can find one that produces the convenient base 111...111 (with appropriate number of ones) then you can xor (^=) your original number. Such a number is easily produced by subtracting 1 from the result of std::bit_ceil.

It's more reliable to cast to unsigned. You'll also need an up-to-date compiler.

Sadly, n=0 is a special case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bit>
 
int bitwiseComplement( int n )
{ 
   return n ? n ^= std::bit_ceil( n + 1u ) - 1 : 1;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << bitwiseComplement( 299475 );
}
```

Output:

```
224812
```

Comment: *'n = 0 is a special case'* – well, actually all negative numbers, it is not specified how these should be handled. In this respect `int` instead of `unsigned` already as parameter is a pretty unlucky choice...

Comment: Fair comment: I checked with the actual Leetcode problem and they wanted 0 <= n < ... so it needs to deal with 0 (but not negative numbers). It would have been simpler with unsigned int used as parameters ... but, again, the original problem wanted int. I only discovered bit_ceil this morning.

Comment: Well, indeed... Though then again they didn't specify how to handle this special case. As for all (other) numbers in the range complement < number applies it might be a fair choice to select -1 on 0 as well to retain this characteristic...

Answer (score 0):

selbie's answer is very good. Also, that answer shows that using the ~ operator requires further work to be done. Here is another solution that works. It is somewhat simpler with less number of binary operations.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int bitwiseComplement(int n) {
        
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }
        int comp_op=0;
        int i=0;
        while(n){
            int bit=n&1;
            int add_val = 0;
            if (bit == 0)
                add_val = 1<<i;
            comp_op += add_val;
            n >>= 1;
            i++;
        }
        return comp_op;
    }
};
```

selbie's point about doing bit twiddling operations with unsigned integers is very true. In this case, the Leet Code problem let's us assume that the number is non-negative (0 <= n < 10^9). Also, the problem statement is not clear what to do when n = 0. The above code is accepted by Leet Code and we could assume that 1 is the expected output when n = 0. Also, they mention that problem 1009 is the same as another one (leetcode.com/problems/number-complement), where the range of n is 1 <= n < 2^31, which is unambiguous.

If in a bit-twiddling problem, n can be negative, a while loop progressing and exiting based on `n>>1` is not a good idea. We should progress the while loop based on number of bits in the representation of the number as it is done in selbie's answer. However, if this Leet Code problem has to be re-framed to allow negative input numbers, the statement of the problem has to be refined carefully and clearly, as to what to expect as output.

As per Aconcagua's comments below,

```
int bit=n&1;
int add_val = 0;
if (bit == 0)
    add_val = 1<<i;
comp_op += add_val;
```

can be compactly implemented as,

```
comp_op |= (!(n&1)) << i;
```

Comment: Not sure if in given context the complement of 0 should indeed be 1 – or instead rather -1. For all other (positive?) numbers applies that the complement of n is smaller than n itself. It it not clear how negative numbers should be treated, though.

Comment: Shouldn't make much a difference but instead of adding I'd prefer OR-ing when dealing with single bits.

Comment: I personally like the more compact and especially *branchless* `comp_op |= !(n&1) << i;` – the bit is inverted directly and OR-ing a 0 is neutral ;)

Comment: Indeed, the Leet Code problem is not very precise about what to do when n = 0. It is mentioned that the problem is the same as another one (https://leetcode.com/problems/number-complement/), where the range of n is 1 <= n < 2^31, which is appropriate.

Comment: `comp_op |= !(n&1) << i;` is a cool approach.

Comment: By the way (for the general case): *If* you introduce the branch already then you can do better by not adding outside the branch, i.e. `if(bit == 0) { int add_val = 1 <<i; comp_op += add_val; }`.